# MySQL caching results with Workbench

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I don't know if it is the database server or the workbench IDE that's caching my results, but I insert data through my application and go to view the result in workbench and there's nothing.

I need to restart the server to see "updated" results.

I tried using `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * from my_table`, without success.

Comment: normally there is refresh button in this kind database tools

Comment: There is certainly no caching involved here. If that were the case no database application would work reliably. You probably are looking at the wrong db or have an open transaction or not really written your values for some reason, even though you think you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @scaisEdge and @Mike.

Now that you said transactions, I tried to commit Workbench's tab, an voilá... it show me new lines...

Altough the documentation says: 
"COMMIT commits the current transaction, **making its changes permanent**.", not to view other transaction changes...

Thanks anyway, it's better than restart server :P

Comment: I'm a bit surprised as well, that I need to commit the transaction on a select before I can select the result of other transactions that are done (and committed!) in a completely different session. Nevertheless, calling `commit;` in MySQL Workbench indeed solves the issue. Alternatively, you can press the commit button at the top of the tab, or check the auto-commit box next to it.